# Java 8 type inference static method call

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Since Java 7 it is allowed to use the diamond operator in order to avoid repeating the type argument. For example

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

becomes

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Why isn't the same notation allowed when using static method calls? For example when creating a [SettableFuture](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html) I'd like to invoke

```
SettableFuture<String> myFuture = SettableFuture.<>create();
```

instead of

```
SettableFuture<String> myFuture = SettableFuture.<String>create();
```

I know it's possible to use the raw method call

```
SettableFuture<String> myFuture = SettableFuture.create();
```

but isn't this just the same as

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList();
```

**My question:** Should I use the raw method call or repeat the type argument when calling generic static methods?

Comment: Do you get a warning from the compiler when using `SettableFuture.create()`? What do you conclude about the type-safety?

Comment: The method call isn't raw. The compiler is figuring out the type parameter from the context.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm actually not sure :/ I just assumed it was type unsafe and therefore never checked in isolation. And sometimes I get type safety warnings and just concluded they originate raw method calls

Comment: They're not unsafe at all. If you got a warning, it came from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java objects are created by means of the **Constructor**. Because this is the normal behavior, Java developers created the empty diamon as a sugar syntax feature.

A static method for object instanciation is not supposed to occur as frequent as the constructor. They are used for a lot of other stuff. Because of that, the syntax is not planned to detect if what you are trying to do is the creation of an object that needs a generic type.

**EDIT:**

I was wrong. There is syntax sugar also for types in static methods (leaving out the diamon) and `create()` is more common than I thought.

**My answer:** I would prefer to leave out the diamon as the type is already specified in the variable and this way you avoid information redundancy in your code.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this, according to Bloch factory methods are preferable in many cases